# Cypher path needs to exclude a certain relation

Tags: neo4j

I have this graph:

```
A-[:X]->B-> a whole tree of badness
A-[:Y]->C-> a whole tree of goodness
```

I would like to know how to specify a path starting with A that excludes the :X relationship.

In this case "Y" could be any one of a number of different edge types. I do not want to specify them explicitly.

How do I write a **path** statement that includes A-[*]-B where * is not :X but can be anything else?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This Cypher query is simpler than the variable-length path query from @MartinPreusse, as it avoids using the `RELATIONSHIPS` function. [Profiling](http://neo4j.com/docs/2.3.0/how-do-i-profile-a-query.html) shows that its execution plan is also a bit simpler, so it might be faster.

```
MATCH p=(a:Label1)-[rels*]-(b:Label2)
WHERE NONE (r IN rels WHERE type(r)= 'X')
RETURN p
```

Comment: This does NOT work. I have a tough case where the only solution was to use:
`MATCH p=(a:Label1)-[*]-(b:Label2)
WHERE NONE (r IN relationships(p) WHERE type(r)= 'X')
RETURN p`

Comment: Can you provide sample data that shows the problem? `rels` is a list of all the relationships in `p`, so should be identical with `relationships(p)`.

Comment: Unfortunatly I can't provide that. I know it sounds crazy, because I tested it on our production database where it didn't work. However, on the default movie database, it did work!

Comment: Are you using the latest neo4j version? May be a fixed bug. Otherwise, you may want to submit a [neo4j issue](https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j/issues).

Comment: We are using 3.3.5, so not the newest? I'll make sure to upgrade to the latest. Good point, thanks!

Comment: That is not the latest. Check neo4j.com.

Answer (score 4):

### Solution for a fixed number of relationships between A and B

You can exclude a relationship type by matching all relationships from `A` to `B` and then filter out a specific type with `WHERE NOT`

```
MATCH p = (a:Label1)-[]-(b:Label2)
WHERE NOT (a)-[:X]-(b)
RETURN p
```

### Solution for a variable length path between A and B

If you have a variable length path between `A` and `B` you cannot put the exact pattern in the `WHERE NOT`. Instead, you can use a `NONE` predicate on the path:

```
MATCH p = (a:Label1)-[*]-(b:Label2)
// this WHERE makes sure that none of the relationships in the
// returned path fulfill the criterion type(relationship) = 'X'
WHERE NONE (r in relationships(p) WHERE type(r) = 'X')
RETURN p
```

Comment: I would add the ALL predicate for his use case where the path is not of depth 1

Comment: @ChristopheWillemsen you mean something like `WHERE NONE (r in relationhips(p) WHERE type(r) = 'Y')`?